# Matplotlib figure not showing up in output widget in first cell of Jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following snippet in the first cell of a Jupyter notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np

out = widgets.Output()
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = 50))
plt.ioff()
with out:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    data.hist(ax = axes)
    display(fig)
plt.ion()    
display(out)
```

If I restart the kernel and run this first cell, I see this output:

```
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
```

However, if I run this first cell a *second* time, I see a matplotlib figure as I intended.  This behavior also shows up if I move everything after the import of matplotlib to a second cell, restart the kernel, and rerun the entire notebook.

Is this difference in behavior intentional?

Comment: Can't reproduce this, neither with the classical jupyter notebook nor with jupyter lab. Can you provide your specs?

Comment: @DanielLenz Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.1 installed in a virtual environment, with Jupyter 4.4.0 and matplotlib 2.2.2 installed via pip.

Comment: I have observed this behavior on Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: What's the purpose of this nested structure?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was trying to create a tab widget with plots on each tab, so I had to wrap the plots in output widgets. I removed the original tab to make the example simpler.

Comment: I don't know if this is supposed to work or not. At least it seems a bit hacky, so maybe the problem of showing a tab widget can be solved differently, circumventing the need for the ion/ioff and context.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you know how to do that, I'd be happy to give it a try. The results I found on Google mentioned `ioff`.

Comment: No sorry, I don't know how to do it; but if you give the code for your use case in the question, someone may have a better idea. The way output and display work in juypter has also changed within the last year, so maybe this broke something or it gives you new options, that are not found by google yet.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842160/how-to-display-matplotlib-plots-in-a-jupyter-tab-widget

Comment: After hit it again. Image widget shown up. Very weird.

Answer (score 4):

The code rearranging and adding magic command '%matplotlib notebook' work for me.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np

out = widgets.Output()

plt.ioff()
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
plt.ion()

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = 50))
data.hist(ax = axes)

display(out)

with out:
    display(fig)
```