# How to display a YouTube video and matplotlib plot side by side on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I'm writing an interactive Jupyter notebook using Ipython and I would like to display a YouTube video side by side with a matplotlib plot.
Each displays properly in itself, but as I try to display them within an HBox they appear one below the other instead of next to each other horizontally. I tried shrinking them, but the behaviour did not change.
Here's an example worked from another one found at [kapernikov.com](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/)

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


SalidaEjes = widgets.Output()

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

with SalidaEjes:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2))
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo

SalidaVideo = widgets.Output()

with SalidaVideo:
    display(YouTubeVideo('RdMj0iMCYfE', width=200, height=200))

Salidas = widgets.HBox([SalidaEjes, SalidaVideo])
display(Salidas)
```

I guess I'm making an obvious mistake but I don't know where.
Any help is appreciated!
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the `HBox` display with empty `SalidaEjes` on the left and then the auto-generated plot below (so `HBox` works ok!). You need to show the plot within the `SalidaEjes` context so that it is not appended after the `HBox` and shown within `HBox`/`SalidaEjes`:

```
with SalidaEjes:
    x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2));
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    plt.show(fig)  # <-- here
```

This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060721/6646912.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! You really helped me. I'm rather new to Python and the Jupyter environment and this small mistakes demand a lot of effort from me. I'm gaining a lot more confidence and knowledge though!